# How can i count the total of all numbers in a .txt file with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, count

So i am trying to make a small batch file that checks different directories of my PC...and it gives me how much files it has with the comand dir i want to add a line to count all the numbers ( ex: 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 1) and give out the tottal.

The text file looks smthn like this -

```
Directory of C:\Mypics

 0 File(s)              0 bytes

Directory of C:\Downloads

  0 File(s)              0 bytes
```

i have tried using this but it doesnt work:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (
    C:\Folder1\*.txt
) do (
    set /a total=0
    for /f "usebackq tokens=166 delims=(s)" %%a in ("%%F") do set /a total+=%%a
    echo %total%
    pause
    echo %total% >>"%%F"
)
pause
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why read a canned status from file instead of directly parsing dir output? Read `help for` for the more complex syntax of the `/f` variant -> your token and delims are nonsense. When setting **and** using a var in a (code block) you need delayedexpansion.

Comment: Sorry i did not understand that i am not a program and this is pretty new to me can u clarify a little please :) Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry but it's unclear to me what result you do **expect**. With that number of just zeroes it's also difficult to guess. "delims=(s)" means the source line is split at the characters `(`,`s` and `)`, `"tokens=166"` means you just want the 166th token from that split (which doesn't exist). Read [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Comment: Ok..i will try reading that thanks. To clarify i have 166 lines in the text file i taught i had to specify how many lines the file has and for the (S) part i was trying to sum the bytes since i cant specify the 0 befor the (S) since i has no delims or the dlims is  space . The result i expect is a tootal of all the numbers infront or behind the word file(s). like Total 0 or total 15 or something like that .

Comment: Ok so i got somewhere i use This now

@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

pause

set /a total=0 1>NUL

for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (FullReport.txt) do set /a total+=%%a

echo %total%

pause it actualy calculates but gives a lot of missing opeartor msgs taht i would like to remove can you help with that :?

Comment: Fixxed it thank you i had to ad a space after the delims: so it doesnt include the word File

Comment: When the loop will be repeaten, the `total` variable will be again 0. If you have fixed your own question, please click the gray-displayed **delete** button under your question.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of files? Or the number of lines in the files? Or the total file size? Or the total number of lines in a specified set of files?